# ServiceStack httpReq.TryResolve<IValidator<T>>(); not resolving correctly?

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

I am implementing my own user registration service based on the built in RegistrationService, so I have copied most of it including the first few lines below...

```
        if (EndpointHost.RequestFilters == null
            || !EndpointHost.RequestFilters.Contains(ValidationFilters.RequestFilter)) //Already gets run
            RegistrationValidator.ValidateAndThrow(request, ApplyTo.Post);


        // Above line does not get hit as there is the ValidationFilters.RequestFilter
        //...but then the code should have previously run validation and failed?
        //...Adding the following line causes the validation to run and fail when expected
       //...but I should not required it as that is the point of the global ValidationFilters.RequestFilter??
        RegistrationValidator.ValidateAndThrow(request, ApplyTo.Post);
```

From what I understand the ValidationFilters.RequestFilter should have been hit earlier and my validation exception thrown.

N.B:  I have put this line at the very end of my apphost configuration.

```
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
```

And I am successfully registering my validator, with this:

```
container.Register<AbstractValidator<UserRegistration>>(new UserRegistrationValidator());
```

...I have now narrowed it down to the following lines of ServiceStack source code in ValidatorCache.cs

```
public class ValidatorCache<T>
{
    public static IValidator GetValidator(IHttpRequest httpReq)
    {
        return httpReq.TryResolve<IValidator<T>>();
    }
}
```

...The TryResolve is not finding the validator.

Comment: Please see my Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the validators were not resolving from the IOC container...rather than delve into this I took a step back and instead found out why the automatic registration method did not work for me previously.

The reason was I originally had this...

```
public interface IUserRegistrationValidator : IValidator<UserRegistration>
{
}

public class UserRegistrationValidator : AbstractValidator<UserRegistration>, IUserRegistrationValidator
{ //..etc
```

And ServiceStack code was tripping up on line shown below for obvious reasons (suggest friendly exception):

```
    public static void RegisterValidator(this Container container, Type validator, ReuseScope scope=ReuseScope.None)
    {
        var baseType = validator.BaseType;
        while (!baseType.IsGenericType) // WOULD FAIL ON THIS LINE HERE
        {
            baseType = baseType.BaseType;
        }

        var dtoType = baseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var validatorType = typeof(IValidator<>).MakeGenericType(dtoType);

        container.RegisterAutoWiredType(validator, validatorType, scope);
    }
```

After getting rid of the pointless interfaces I was playing around with I can use the automatic method of registering validators...such as:

```
container.RegisterValidators(typeof(UserRegistrationValidator).Assembly);
```

Which resolves my issues, I am not 100% sure how I would manually register the UserValidator from https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation and have it work as I am still somewhat under impression that the following would not work properly.

```
container.Register<AbstractValidator<User>>(new UserValidator());
```

...I am likely wrong of course!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered registering validators in the `AppHost.cs`?

```
// This method scans the assembly for validators
container.RegisterValidators(Assemblies);
```

Comment: Yes I have registered the validators, but the not via the automatic method above as it didn't work for me.  I will update my question later with the lines that do that.  N.B My question explains that the validation itself does work when called explicitly in my service rather than via ValidationFilters.RequestFilter.